# Parent div's scrollbar accessible through fixed positioned child with higher z-index

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am facing a weird issue with scrollbar behavior when trying to implement overlay layer in my application.

My application's main container is relatively positioned and has z-index set to 1 (this part of an application is kinda a black-box for me, so I am looking for a solution that doesn't require major changes in main container styling). Main container usually has horizontal scrollbar at the bottom - as content are is filled with "blades" (similar design to the Azure portal) that are stacking to the right from one another.

Simplified styles of main container:

```
.main-container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 120%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

Then my application has an overlay layer - the one that covers the whole screen and might display whole another flow with multiple blades in it. Overlay layer is simple styles as "position:fixed" and stretched to fill the whole screen by next styles:

```
.overlay-fixed-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5);
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

So what happens is that for some reason I am able to click and drag parent's container horizontal scrollbar "through" overlay layer. Overlay layer is fully covering its parent (as it is filling whole viewport area) - but for some reason it acts like it is completely transparent for the area where parent's scrollbar is positioned.

I have created very simplified repro example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-woqq3y?file=index.html

As I understand I am facing some issue with stacking context, but I can't find the reason for such behavior. Especially weird part is that none of the parent's container children are accessible "through" overlay expect for the scrollbar - i.e. buttons or links are not clickable, while scrollbar is reacting to the mouseover events and is fully draggable and functional.

Additional notes: ideally I am looking for the fix that does not require JS interaction or any modifications of parent container. I understand that it is possible to disable scroll on parent container while overlay is opened - but it is not applicable in my specific case, as I am working on MFE application that has no control of its host and should not try to modify any elements of it's host.

I have tried to play with different z-indexes for both parent container and fixed overlay - but no luck. I tried adding/removing opacity from the overlay container - and it doesn't change anything either.

The issue disappears when I remove specific z-index from my parent container, but that is a part of a quiz that I have no control of.

Also, I am really interested in understanding the root cause of such behavior - because currently I have no explanation for what I am seeing.

Comment: You've mentioned in the question that the overlay is supposed to cover the entire screen, but in the demo that you've linked, the overlay does not cover the parent at all. What exactly is the intended area of coverage for the overlay?

Comment: In the css styling for the overlay, in the question, you've stated that the value for `top` is 0, but in the demo it is 150px. Which one of these is the actual value?

Comment: It doesn't really matter, I have made the demo with top offset just to better display the issue how overlay can be "transparent" for scrollbars but not for other controls. If you change styles to have overlay top:0 - it has zero effect on the reproducing actual issue.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I misunderstood your question. When I was using the touchpad to try and scroll from through the overlay, the parent wasn't scrolling, unless I was in the area that was not covered. Thats why I wondered why you hadn't just covered the entire thing. I read the question again and now noticed the part where you said to actually click and drag the scrollbar

Answer (score 0):

The reason why that is happening is because the placement of elements matters. If 2 elements are placed on the 'same level` so to speak, then z-index can affect which goes on top/bottom.

However no matter how high a z-index you apply to a child element, it can never truly come out of the parent itself. There's always a hierarchy maintained, which is what the scroll is following.

So in your case, what's happening is that although `.fixed-child` is layered over the parent, that scrollbar is still registered as being outside `.fixed-child`, since it is attached to the parent element.

If you were to able to modify the html layout, and have both these elements on the same level, then your code would work as expected:

```css
.scrollable-parent {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 120%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-child {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  /* any background will work */
  /* background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.5); */
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    #606dbc,
    #606dbc 10px,
    #465298 10px,
    #465298 20px
  );
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Sample styles which are not directly related to the issue but are added as a hints to better undestand the issue */

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wide-child {
  width: 120%;
}

.static-hint {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.button-sample {
  margin-top: 120px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scrollable-parent">
      <h1 class="wide-child">Parent content</h1>
      <button class="button-sample">Not clickable button</button>
      <a href="https://www.stackoverflow.com">Not clickable link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="fixed-child">
    <h1 style="margin-top: 100px">Child popup content</h1>
    <h2 class="static-hint">
      <p>Try to scroll parent container through fixed child overlay:</p>
      ↓
    </h2>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However you said that you're not able to modify this code. In which case my next suggestion would've been accomplishing this with some JS. But since you can't use that as well, then we're stuck, since I don't think that this is something that can be managed with just css alone.